# Handling lots of drawables in android project

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I am beginner in Android development. I need to show 400+ images in my android app. Right now I am putting all of them in my drawable folder, but this doesn't seem good, as my apk becomes too large in size. What should I do? Can I play with images' resolution and all? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

best solution will be to put them in web and then displaying it through lazy list, But if thats not an option then only thing you can do is to compress your image to a extent it is acceptable, that will check you problem of large apk size.

try PNGOUT , a great tool for compressing images.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in a extension-obb-File:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

So I handled it with videos.